# Emberjs object loses its property after computed sort

Tags: ember.js

I have a table component, which receives a model what i call content.

```
{{my-table content=model }}
```

This model get sorted into a computed property (CP).

```
multiSort: Ember.computed.sort('content','sortProperitsWithOrders')
```

I loop through the `multiSort` and pass each row to the a row component

```
  {{#each row in multiSort}} 
    {{my-table-row row=row columns=columns}}
  {{/each}}
```

In each row I have a checkbox component. If it changes, an action is sent up to its parent component (the row component). From the row I send the action further to the table component (action up), where I toggle the row's active property.

The **problem**: after I use sort, the `row` lose its *active* property, and the checkbox is unchecked. Check a checkbox then hit the header of a column.

I would think `Ember.compute.sort` takes the content and rearrange it based on `sortProperitsWithOrders`. So if I set the `active` property on one of the content's item, then I will have it in the `multiSort` CP. From `multiSort` it will pass down to the row component, and from the row to the checkbox (data down).

### JsBin: http://jsbin.com/mojuquhawo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Can you create a simple jsbin which doesn't have these many columns & unused components.

Comment: @kushdilip i'm still debugging. It looks the problem is the checkbox component: If it re-renders, its state does't reflect the checked property, which is based on the row's active property. The row does NOT lose the property. Everything works as I expected, just the checkbox loses its state after re-rendering. I'm on to rewrite the checkbox component. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that a new instance of `MyTableRowComponent` is created for each row each time you sort. When this happens the `active` property (which originates from `MyTableRowComponent`) is set to its initial value of `false`.

See example [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/susopeqepi/2/edit?js,console,output) showing a new component being created on each sort - look at the console logging.

You need somewhere to store the `active` property where it persists - the `Customer` model seems like the most appropriate place.

Also I notice that `MyCheckboxComponent` is not extending from `Ember.Checkbox` - instead it's using an `Ember.Component` - this will likely cause issues as well.